# Laravel Pusher/Echo/Soketi AccessDeniedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs3, laravel-sanctum, laravel-echo

So, I'm attempting to use laravel jetstream inertia with vue with no ssr. When trying to use broadcast private channels with laravel-echo I keep getting AccessDeniedHttpException exception with no message. I will put the error message bellow.

I will also add my Broadcast provider file the echo class I'm using with headers etc, headers from the response of /broadcast/auth and I should state that I'm also using soketi with laravel sail I can see soketi working and getting messages. I will also provide my composer.json file.

I'm just trying to target the products search event that will return products based on the query search and the page. It targets the channel with PrivateChannel('products-'.Auth::user()->id)

Any help would be great here I have been at this for 4 days and I'm not getting anything in the error logs. I'm starting to think this is a bug with laravel anyone can help me track this down? I should also mention that I use the same middleware on my api endpoints and have no issue and do not get this error.

vue.js echo initiation code.

```
let echo = ref(new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ? import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST : `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    authEndpoint:  '/broadcasting/auth',
    auth: {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': value,
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token.content,
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + props.user_token,
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        authorizer: (channel, options) => {
            return {
                authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
                    axios.post('/broadcasting/auth', {
                        socket_id: socketId,
                        channel_name: channel.name
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        callback(null, response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        callback(error);
                    });
                }
            };
        },
    }
}));

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    console.log('Token Set: ', props.user_token);
    echo = echo.value.private('converters-' + props.user.id);
});
```

Headers Returned From /broadcasting/auth

```
POST /broadcasting/auth HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Bearer 9|zXngnhwkqWJERsRj6LEpR8W5cZjNpbiswOin6Y09
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 70
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json
Cookie: remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d=eyJpdiI6IjdLZzZZUW04bkZ5aFFNMkxNbS8vQ2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUjJxU3dlVW40ZXBpOUNvQWRicnFrdHhvOS9FUU44QVFaNitFeC9UOERQVU5zKzI5S0YxUGlIRDVQMjhWc2ZaWC9zeVlOMGNicTUvWldrVWNYNThEMVZYeWpLdm5NUlRHb3V1MUZyd002NHR4VFlZSWl5TTllODdxYmRlRkFERFJBeEhuY2dtVkNrWXh4TDRpQ2VybThmOGxHOVc4blpmUUV6TXJURDdYcWpuWVN0YTc4VEdBbTE4RGtQRlM0RnU3am9PR0pKejR4Ti9KeEJwTG5xQkhUNmtkblBucXUwT2MwQjZ5MVRoVnVNYz0iLCJtYWMiOiJkYmE0N2MyNWJkZWY3OTQ4NmQ4ZWEyYTdlZjIyZGMyZTIwMDU4NmYyNWJjYzA4MmNmZTU1ZmYzODUzMjMwYzRmIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImozaThEN2RwdENQWElnZzNUbjBhZkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaDQ0ekFCYkEwVDVlT2E0Z2JLcDdKVWVISzlxeHBmM0xsREdpcWQ1U1AxQTFQQnZ5c0VaWHhpZThkQ0dpL2w2Q2xJSlZMKzUrdmxXbm5aS2hndC80M2VrNElCdmhMREN0NXlzYk9mZjlRT25kd0V6R2hOTytWTlAvNFdCblJyU2EiLCJtYWMiOiIwNTE3ZGNiYTYzYjNmMmM0YzI4ZDM5NDMyYmJmYzk5NTNiN2VmY2M2Mzk4NDdhYmUyNmNkMmM5OTczNmRiZDE1IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; kanect_session=eyJpdiI6Iis0ZmZNRnlqcDVGcEVURkhyc04ySUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoib2g4V1FzRGU5ODlLVUFSL2NuUE5FSE9FSDVnMS8rSEdGYXJSODk1YXhXUFFuZTRBVEVSayszdzVDZXZQa3EraGIzWXE5SHVQUCtremx6QXh5WGZvTGw0bUlLN05UNE9JZUIwYUxJSm5aTUEvRHkrdjV5RWxxTTFrNWU3UHJvaTMiLCJtYWMiOiJjMTMzMDQyNTZkM2Q0Y2UwMDliMWExMzc1ZWY4ZWY5NzdlMzJhMzIyNWUwMTlkNzI2MDdjNjIxMDczZWUxN2VkIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D
Host: 127.0.0.1
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/products
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: bDvUKbUaXr03MsTL7Uq5EKQHJKh0EBtXoamKFzRn
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6ImozaThEN2RwdENQWElnZzNUbjBhZkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaDQ0ekFCYkEwVDVlT2E0Z2JLcDdKVWVISzlxeHBmM0xsREdpcWQ1U1AxQTFQQnZ5c0VaWHhpZThkQ0dpL2w2Q2xJSlZMKzUrdmxXbm5aS2hndC80M2VrNElCdmhMREN0NXlzYk9mZjlRT25kd0V6R2hOTytWTlAvNFdCblJyU2EiLCJtYWMiOiIwNTE3ZGNiYTYzYjNmMmM0YzI4ZDM5NDMyYmJmYzk5NTNiN2VmY2M2Mzk4NDdhYmUyNmNkMmM5OTczNmRiZDE1IiwidGFnIjoiIn0=
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {   
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);
        
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

In the routes/channels.php I'm trying to connect to a private channel that just returns true for now.

```
Broadcast::channel('private-products-{user_id}', ProductsChannel::class);
```

Here is my composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.6",
        "http-interop/http-factory-guzzle": "^1.2",
        "inertiajs/inertia-laravel": "^0.6.8",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.8",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^3.1",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/scout": "^10.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "laravel/vapor-cli": "^1.56",
        "laravel/vapor-core": "^2.31",
        "meilisearch/meilisearch-php": "^1.1",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2",
        "tightenco/ziggy": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laracasts/generators": "^2.0",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Here are my config/auth.php guards.

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],  
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 30,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Here is the error being returned from the client side.

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\AccessDeniedHttpException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php",
    "line": 82,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastManager.php",
            "line": 479,
            "function": "auth",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\Broadcasters\\PusherBroadcaster",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php",
            "line": 353,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastManager",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastController.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "__callStatic",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "authenticate",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 43,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 259,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 205,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 797,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 796,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 775,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 739,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 728,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 200,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/vapor-core/src/Http/Middleware/ServeStaticAssets.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Laravel\\Vapor\\Http\\Middleware\\ServeStaticAssets",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
            "line": 40,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 39,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 175,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 144,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/public/index.php",
            "line": 51,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php",
            "line": 16,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you make sure that .env has 'VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY', 'VITE_PUSHER_APP_SECRET', and 'PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER' values inside?

Comment: and ensure that the auth middleware is applied to the broadcasting routes. you can specify like this.
```Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);```

Comment: Yes these are all things I checked I thought that was clear in my explanation?

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?